# consume next value of hot observable using take and toPromise

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

i have a hot observable that i often need to trigger manually.  i've used a `Subject` to achieve this.  i want to:

- trigger the subject
- capture the *next* output of the inner observable
- trigger the subject, again
- capture the *next* output, again

you can observe me try and fail in the following script. i think the script shows clear intent, but doesn't execute per expectation.  can you pinpoint what im missing?

```
void async function () {
  var subject = new Rx.Subject()
  var inner = subject.combineLatest([subject]).share()
  // ^^ i have other observables here in addition to the subject
  // in my real use case.  also, i want the observable hot!
  var i = 1
  while (i <= 3) {
    console.log(`i is ${i}, print ${i} before "i is ${i + 1}"`)
    var singleValObs = inner.take(1) // prep to observe the next value
    subject.next(i) // trigger the next value
    var [val] = await singleValObs.toPromise()
    console.log(val)
    ++i
  }
}()
```

i expect 1, 2, & 3 to be logged, but just one line is logged!

i'm new to rx, but really like the ideas behind it.  thanks for the tips in advanced!

Comment: The final Promise never resolves because the stream is empty and never completes. Can't tell you why execution halts at the destructured assignment. I verified this by stacking the promises (removing await) up into an array. Console logging the array will show you two resolved promises and the last never resolves. This is also consistent with the `toPromise()` documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your promise is created after the subject emitted the value so it never gets resolved. You must first create the promise, then invoke `next(i)` and then await the promise, specifically:

```
var singleValObs = inner.take(1) // prep to observe the next value
var promise = singleValObs.toPromise();
subject.next(i) // trigger the next value
var [val] = await promise
```

Alternatively, use `ReplaySubject` which will emit the value to late subscribers as well.